Can I use black in a Genku commander deck?
Genku, Future Shaper is a white/blue card that includes this ability:

Whenever another nontoken permanent you control leaves the battlefield, choose one that hasn't been chosen this turn. Create a creature token with those characteristics.

2/2 white Fox with vigilance.
1/2 blue Moonfolk with flying.
1/1 black Rat with lifelink.


Can I use black in a Genku commander deck because of his ability to make 1/1 black rat tokens?

No, you can not use black, red, and/or green cards in a Genku commander deck.
What matters for commander deck construction is color identity:

903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

Genku's color identity is white and blue. Color words don't count.
